# Synchronized Neighbours

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an array of object of type `A`. Each object has a value and a reference to the next object in the array. It also has a method `process`, which manipulates the value of the object, and the value of the following (next) object.

```
public class A{
    private int value;
    private A next;

    public void process(){
        //manipulates the value of this and of next
    }
}
```

In my main method I have created multiple Threads of type `B`, which call the `process`-method of some objects in the array.

Therefore I want to create a lock around the value. Multiple Threads shouldn't be allowed to simultaneously manipulate the value of a certain objects. But the problem is, if I declare the `process`-method `synchronized`, than still a thread processing `array[0]` and a thead processing `array[1]` are able to manipulate the value of `array[1]`. A call of `array[1].process()`, should wait, until all `array[0].process()` and `array[1].process()` finished.

How can I create a lock around each neighbour pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `process` acquire two locks: one for this object, and one for the next one. Something like this:

```
public void process() {
    synchronized (this) {
        synchronized (next) {
            // manipulate the value of this and of next
        }
    }
}
```

This answer should raise a huge red flag in your head. *Any* time you acquire multiple locks, you must convince yourself that they won't deadlock!

A deadlock can only happen if two threads try to acquire the locks in a different order, though (ie, one locks A then B, the other locks B then A). In this case, that can't happen -- a previous object is always locked before its next object.

So, when `array[0].process()` is invoked, it lock on `array[0]` and `array[1]`. When `array[1].process()` is invoked, it'll try to lock on `array[1]`, which will block until `array[0].process()` is finished. When that happens, it'll acquire the lock on `array[1]`, and then try to acquire the lock on `array[2]`, as well.

It's still possible to deadlock, though. If the code in `process` spins up a new thread which then tries to call `process` on the previous object, and then tries to join on that thread, it'll deadlock. For instance, if `array[1].process()` does this, then that thread will try to acquire locks for `array[0]` and `array[1]`. It won't be able to do this until `array[1].process()` finishes, which won't happen until the thread returns -- and thus deadlock.

For this reason, you should be *very* careful about allowing `process` to be "pluggable" (as in, somebody passes in an interface or extends a method to determine how the manipulation is done. Generally, executing any sort of "outside code" in that way is dangerous when done under a lock.

But if `process` is totally under your control, and doesn't spin up any threads, then you should be fine because of the constant order in which the locks are acquired.

In situations like this where there's a bit of a delicate dance, it's not uncommon to acquire the locks not on `this`, but on a custom object just for the occasion:

```
public class A {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private int value;
    private A next;

    public void process() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            synchronized (next.lock) {
                // etc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This protects you from somebody coming in and synchronizing on one of your objects and disrupting that delicate dance. It also serves as a visual reminder to anyone who's reading the code, that something interesting is happening with respect to synchronization.